# same words in different contexts with Word2Vec

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec

I want to use Word2Vec to represent words by vectors.

If there are 2 identical words in the Word2Vec's input,
is it possible to get a different representation for them?

Are there different methods to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, great question.
I found a link that explains how to avoid duplicates when representing words with vectors using python.
https://towardsdatascience.com/learn-word2vec-by-implementing-it-in-tensorflow-45641adaf2ac

You can split the text and avoid word duplication in the following way:

```
corpus_raw = 'He is the king . The king is royal . She is the royal  queen '
# convert to lower case
corpus_raw = corpus_raw.lower()

# ---- dictionary words -> int and int -> words ----
words = []
for word in corpus_raw.split():
    if word != '.': # because we don't want to treat . as a word
        words.append(word)
words = set(words) # so that all duplicate words are removed
word2int = {}
int2word = {}
vocab_size = len(words) # gives the total number of unique words
for i,word in enumerate(words):
    word2int[word] = i
    int2word[i] = word

print(words)
```

Comment: Thanks,I want to save the context.
In my task, I need to save the context of each identical word and that's why I want to save a vector of each word

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've modified my previous answer to include the relevant code. 
This splits the string into individual words and removes duplicates.

Comment: I want to preserve the context of the word for calling word2vec. How can preserve the context?

Comment: What do you mean by preserve the context?
By context, do you mean its position in the text?

Comment: In my mission, each word has a label.  Hence, I want to preserve the context of each word in the sentence because I can get 2 labels of a words in different contexts

Comment: In this case, you would need to implement a "skip gram model". Here is another link that explains it in more detail.
https://towardsdatascience.com/skip-gram-nlp-context-words-prediction-algorithm-5bbf34f84e0c